# Gráfico de dispersão no ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2, r

Fala galera estou querendo criar um gráfico de dispersão no R usando o `ggplot2`, um gráfico de dispersão com tamanho do gene (lengthbp) X variantes (frameshift, splice_acceptor, splice_donor, stop_gained), a figura abaixo mostra a tabela utilizada para produzir o gráfico de dispersão:

[Link para o Dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IT-GAzi51JYvEs5_NpwYScqAu4rqklWB/view?usp=sharing)

[image: Tabela de tamanho dos genes e variantes]

O problema é que não estou conseguindo pegar todas essas colunas de variantes destacadas em vermelho no gráfico acima e utilizar no código abaixo:

```
library ggplot2
    ggplot(gnomad_length, aes(frameshift, lengthbp))+
      geom_point()
```

A figura abaixo é o gráfico de dispersão de apenas uma variante, veja no `eixo x` deveria está todas as variantes e não apenas `frameshift`:

[image: Gráfico de dispersão length x variante]

Comment: Marlon, boa tarde! Disponibilize o dataset na sua pergunta para quem for tentar te ajudar poder testar. Abraço!

Comment: segue o link liberado [link para o dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IT-GAzi51JYvEs5_NpwYScqAu4rqklWB/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para usar diferentes variáveis no ggplot, seus dados precisam estar em formato longo. Há várias opções para isso:

```
dados <- read.table(
  "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=1IT-GAzi51JYvEs5_NpwYScqAu4rqklWB&export=download",
  header = TRUE)

dados.l <- tidyr::pivot_longer(dados,
  cols = c("frameshift", "splice_acceptor", "splice_donor", "stop_gained"),
  names_to = "variante")
# ou
dados.l <- reshape2::melt(dados,
  measure.vars = c("frameshift", "splice_acceptor", "splice_donor", "stop_gained"),
  variable.name = "variante")
# ou, com mesma sintaxe: reshape::melt ou data.table::melt
```

Gerando o gráfico:

```
library(ggplot2)

# No mesmo plot, com cores diferentes para cada variante:
ggplot(dados.l, aes(value, lengthbp, color = variante)) +
  geom_point()

# Um plot para cada variante no mesmo gráfico:
ggplot(dados.l, aes(value, lengthbp)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ variante)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou com o diplyr.